# Google Map for Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, callback

I am new to mobile programming and trying out the google map v3 tutorial,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            alert('init');
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: latlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
        }
        var myKey = "mykey";
        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+myKey+"&sensor=false&callback=initialize";
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadScript()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 400px; height: 400px">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this using my computer in netbean, everything works, but when i download it into my android device (as an application), the callback function ( initialize ) is never called. Anyone know what is the problem to this?

Thanks

Comment: do you have javascript enabled on your android device (the browser might have it disabled) check that setting.

Comment: yup i have javascript enabled on my android device.

Answer (score 0):

First off all download phone gap plugin

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

try to run the above code in the mobile/emulator ,then you can have sample map displayed